# Lost websocket connection on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I didn't find an answer that fix an issue with lost websocket connection in NodeJS.

Here is the scenario: I've a real-time dashboard on browser where users are connected via websocket and the Node App sends events to all clients connected when something happens (for example, an user change is status).
Sometimes, the users don't receive the event because their websocket connection are closed by Node with ECONNRESET or ETIMEDOUT error.

I use this module:
https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node (1.0.23)
for create websocket server and I set up with this values in this moment:

```
keepalive: true,
keepaliveInterval: 20000,
keepaliveGracePeriod: 10000,
dropConnectionOnKeepaliveTimeout: false,
disableNagleAlgorithm: true,
fragmentOutgoingMessages: false,
closeTimeout: 10000
```

To fix this issue, I tried the follows solutions:

- disable keepalive of module and write a custom keepalive with setInterval and setTimeout for every websocket connection;
- calc the latency of round trip message (in my test on with lan, wi-fi and 4G is
  is on average 10ms)
- enable keepalive of module and remove my custom keepalive;
- set dropConnectionOnKeepaliveTimeout to false;
- increase closeTimeout from 5secs to 10secs
- add log on event error when websocket is closed - (with this log, I see that the latency of users is very high, more than 10 seconds)
- set "0" the value of timeout on server HTTPS

I need that the websocket connections keep connected for a long time and only if there is an internet connection problem (example cable broken), the node close the websocket connections. This situation is already handle.

Are there any params that I need to change in Node to avoid this behaviour and fix this
issue? A user VPN or router used in home connection can be the problems?

Here are versions of software and module:

- NodeJS v6.14.4 (I know is old but is a legacy project and I can't update)
- Debian 10
- WebSocket-Node (1.0.23) (https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node)
- Browser Chrome (latest) and Firefox (latest)